# how to set id from foreignkey to other column name in django

Tags: python, django

i have model mykategori

```
class mykategori(models.Model):
    w_id_kategori = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    w_nama_kategori = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.w_nama_kategori
```

and myblog

```
class myblog(models.Model):
    w_id_article = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    w_kategori = models.ForeignKey(mykategori)
    w_penulis = models.ForeignKey(User,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.w_judul
```

and this is my view in myblog app

```
from .models import myblog
def index(request):
   blog={}
   blog['data']=myblog.objects.all()
   blog['title']="Halaman Utama"
   return render(request,'myblog/index.html',blog)
```

and this is my index.html

```
{% for blog in data %}
      {{blog.w_kategori}}
{% endfor %}
```

if i run it, it will show id from mykategori app in index.html, how can i print w_nama_kategori if i use `{{blog.w_kategori}}`?

Answer (score 1):

First the `id`fields are not necessary Django puts it by default.

to get the  `w_nama_kategori` attribute in templates, you should use `{{blog.w_kategori.w_nama_kategori}}`